# can't set my xampp to work with any php debugger

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, xdebug

i have been trying to set my XAMPP to work with xdebug php debugger, i have edited the php.ini file with the following parameters:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:\Program Files\Development\xampp\php\ext/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

after restarting the server the phpinfo() still is not showing any sign of the xdbug.

in general my php.ini looks a little bit different from what i have remembered, there is no [zend] section in it. 
another wierd thing is that all the tutorials talk about a php.ini file that is located in 
xampp\apache\bin\php.ini, but there is no such file there. the only php.ini file i have is located at xampp\php directory.

i have reinstalled the xampp again and the files still looks the same.

i am using XP using the latest xampp 1.7.2

please advise
thanks

Comment: also having this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a php.ini in xamp\apache\bin, you may need to copy the one you're working on to that folder.

It may also be helpful to check the output of phpinfo() in a browser to see what php.ini is being used by apache. It will be labeled "Loaded Configuration File" in the first block table on the page. Make sure that the php.ini file you are editing is the one listed there.

Also, I'd suggest not mixing / and \ in a file path:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:\Program Files\Development\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you go [here](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll) you will see all available versions of xdebug dll .. the most recent is 
[php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll) - the one that actually WORKS under xampp(lite) is  [php_xdebug-2.0.0-5.2.2.dll](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.0.0-5.2.2.dll) .. Since moving back to that older version, i am reliably debugging PHP in Eclipse like its visual studio

BTW -- i am using xampp 1.7.1 because 1.7.2 has php 5.3 and that doesn't work in CLI mode reliably under Windows 7 at the mo

Comment: hi scott,
can you send/post me the files that you have added to the php.ini?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "zend_extension_ts" and try "zend_extension".   I've found various different explanations as to why ([threaded server vs non](http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/1059.html), [debug build vs regular](http://drupal.org/node/147267#comment-889061)).

Also ensure you are not loading it with an 'extension=' line anywhere else.

You will know it's loaded when you see

```
        This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
        Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
            with Xdebug v2.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2008, by Derick Rethans
```

in your phpinfo() output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more info around re this issue?

I also am running xampp 1.7.2 build, with PHP5.3 and NetBeans 6.8 and consistently get 'Socket Exception Occurred' error with advice to remove watches. Debugging without watches is pretty boring!

SpecialOne - did you get sorted?